# How Could I Update a table with conditions from other table

Tags: sql, oracle, join, sql-update

I Have the Table "Person" and the table "Fisica" which is the extention of "Person". Both tables are related by the field name Id, and I want to update the tables based on conditions that include both tables.
For example:

```
Tables:
Persona(Id, Name, Money)
Fisica(Id, LastName, Year)
```

With data:

```
Persona(1, X, 5)
Persona(2, A, 10)
Fisica(1, Y, 1990)
Fisica(2, B, 2000)
```

I want to set Persona.Name=some_Value, Fisica.LastName=other_Value and Fisica.Year=number when Persona.Name='X', so it results

```
Persona(1, some_Value, 5)
Persona(2, A, 10)
Fisica(1, other_Value, number)
Fisica(2, B, 2000)
```

I am working in Oracle

Comment: You show two wrong query but dont say what is the result you want. Show us db schema, sample data and desire output. please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
     And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't update two tables with one statement. So you need two `UPDATE` statements.

So you have to update one, then the other. The question is, which one first?

It doesn't really matter, but if you update Persona first and change the name, then you have to use the new name when updating Fisica. Like this:

```
update Persona
set name = 'some_Value'
where name = 'current_Name'
;
update Fisica
set lastname = 'other_Value',
    year = number
where id = (
  select id
  from Persona
  where name = 'some_Value'
)
;
```

If you update Fisica first, you use the old value of name both times, like this:

```
update Fisica
set lastname = 'other_Value',
    year = number
where id = (
  select id
  from Persona
  where name = 'current_Value'
)
;
update Persona
set name = 'some_Value'
where name = 'current_Value'
;
```

note `number` has to be replaced with an actual numeric value.

Good coding practice would be to put both statements in the same transaction and commit only if they are both successful.

Answer (score 0):

Though Oracle don't provide such functionality as compare to mysql where we can write query like this:

```
Update table1 t1, table2 t2 set t2.field2="ABC" where t1.id=t2.id
```

But you can update multiple tables using single query in Oracle for Views.

So create the view for the above two tables `Persona, Fisica` and write query as follows:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW  "Persona_Fisica" ("PersonaID", "Name", "Money", "FisicaID", "Lastname", "Year") AS 
      select P.Id as PersonaID,
        Name as Name,
        Money as Money,
        F.Id as FisicaID,
        LastName as Lastname,
        year as Year
     from Persona P,
        Fisica F 
     where P.ID=F.ID
/
Update Persona_Fisica set Name=some_Value, LastName=other_Value,Year=number were Name='X',
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was wondering if the query you mentioned for mysql (Update table1 t1, table2 t2 set t2.field2="ABC" where t1.id=t2.id) works in Sql Server.